# C++ Template characters in single tick as argument

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I make it short. The code:

```
typedef int NAME;

template <NAME, typename T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:

    MyTemplate(T value)
    {
        value_type = value;
    }

    T value_type;

    operator T& const ()
    {
        return value_type;
    }
};
```

And in in main:

```
MyTemplate<'val', int> number1(1);
```

I tumbled across this kind of code a while ago and I just rebuilt it by memorizing. What is confusing to me is the `val` as the first template argument. Also, if I pass more than 4 characters the compiler will complain.
So what could be the purpose of the `NAME` in the template and why can I pass a `string` in single ticks? I'm also not sure if the code I saw a while ago had the typedef in it but without it it won't compile.

Comment: What is `'val'`? that's not a `char` literal.

Comment: @user0042 It's a multicharacter literal, which is a type of character literal. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal #6

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sure that's a valid one?

Comment: So you are asking about code you did not write, not understand the purpose of, not remember where you got it and are not sure whether the code you are asking about is actually to the code you show?

Comment: @Yunnosch It was a fragment of code I saw, yes. Did I find an answer to my question ? No, because I googled for a lot of stuff but not for the right thing. Sorry for asking here if I don't know what actually to search for. Sorry also if I disturbed your emotional state.

Answer (score 3):

`'val'` is a [multi-character literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal). Its type is `int` (rather than `char`, as ordinary character literals use in C++). its numeric value is implementation-defined. It is distinct from a string literal.